# convert date format from mmddyy to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:sec

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I have a `date` format which I extracted from filename. this `date` is in format `'mmddyy'`.

I want to `convert` it into `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:sec'` format.

For example
`Date = 083115 -- mm = 08,dd=31,yy=15`

`Result date = 2015-08-31:00:00:00
time will always be 00:00:00`

I am using `SQL server 2012`

thanks

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121). This function will produce required results.

Comment: @MUHAMMADTASADDUQALI Using a style of `121` will also give milliseconds.  This doesn't seem to be what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution

```
DECLARE @Date nvarchar(10)
SET @Date = '083115'
SELECT  CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@Date,2)+LEFT(@Date,2)+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2))
```

this will give you 2015-08-31 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to louis from sql server central.com, i got the solution

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1715611-3077-1.aspx

DECLARE @D nvarchar(6) = '083115'

SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, SUBSTRING(@D, 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(@D, 1, 4), 12)